# how to properly include or get file contents in a wordpress theme

Tags: templates

here is the code I added to a folder inside my theme directory i.e wp-content/themes**/THEMENAME/audiounity/**

```
<?php
$data_file = unserialize(base64_decode(file_get_contents(' get_template_directory() . "/audiounity/website_setting.conf"')));
```

here is the error I got after viewing a post

**Warning: file_get_contents( get_template_directory() . "/audiounity/website_setting.conf"): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/unerdportfolio/public_html/wp-content/themes/frontier/audiounity/result.php on line 2**

note: my folder name is audiounity

---

clarification

i used this code below **the_content();**

```
<?php
    include( get_template_directory() . '/audiounity/result.php' ); 

     ?>
```

inside this result.php is where am trying to call **...get_template_directory() . "/audiounity/website_setting.conf"')));**

Comment: Did you try w/o the apostrophes?

Comment: No... I don't know about it yet. I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: Is `audiounity` the name of your theme?

Comment: @TomJNowell audiounity is the name of my folder in the theme.                                                                    theme name is frontier

Comment: is it a child theme?

Comment: @rudtek not a child theme

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/audiounity/result.php' );
```

The result of this is likely:

`/srv/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/audiounity/audiounity/result.php`

The first line of the Codex entry for that function is:

> Retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme.

If it's a child theme, then you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory`. `*_template_*` functions always refer to the parent theme, `*_stylesheet_*` functions refer to the active theme

### A Bigger Problem You've Missed

`$data_file = unserialize(base64_decode(file_get_contents(' get_template_directory() . "/audiounity/website_setting.conf"')));`

- .conf files will be readable to all, anybody can download your themes `.conf` file, would it not make more sense to store it inside a PHP file as a PHP array?
- `unserialize` will unserialize a PHP structure, which exposes you to a PHP object injection attack. Avoid serialising and deserialising PHP

If you want to store a configuration, you have 2 options:

- use JSON, `json_encode` and `json_decode`
- use a PHP array in a file

If you need to modify these files, don't, use them as defaults and store the changes in the database as options

Comment: config file already encrypted

Comment: serialising and base64 encoding isn't encryption, anybody can undo the transformation via `<?php echo unserialize(base64_decode(file_get_contents('downloadedfile.conf' ) ) );`, but if it's a PHP array in a PHP file, it becomes a non-issue. Encryption won't prevent the security problem either